# Return of Capital and Non-Cash (Phantom) Distributions for U.S. ETFs

Tags: taxes, canada, etf, cost-basis, canada-revenue-agency

I think I finally have a understanding on how to calculate the Adjusted Cost Base (ACB) for my taxable Canadian securities. (Keep track of all buys and sells, use [CDS Innovations](http://services.cds.ca/applications/taxforms/taxforms.nsf/PROCESSED-EN-?OpenView&Start=1&Count=3000&RestrictToCategory=T3-2013) to determine if there were any Return of Capital (RoC) and/or non-cash (aka Phantom) distributions and then enter everything into [Adjustedcostbase.ca](https://www.adjustedcostbase.ca/index.cgi)).

However, for my taxable U.S. securities I'm not sure if there are such phantom  distributions and rarely do I see any RoCs. Looking at [IWR](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239718/ishares-russell-midcap-etf) for example (under the Distributions tab) all I can see are the normal distributions and some RoCs from 2007 and earlier. Is this normal? Am I looking in the wrong place? Are U.S. securities fundamentally different than Canadian ones in that they don't have phantom distributions?

Comment: Return OF Capital (literally just giving back your money) is a still a taxable distribution from US ETFs for Canadians.  As to your question [this article](http://cawidgets.morningstar.ca/articletemplate/articlegl.aspx?id=533682]) implies it's rare in the US.

Comment: Thanks, I got RoC correct in the title at least. I assume the [link should be this instead](http://cawidgets.morningstar.ca/articletemplate/articlegl.aspx?id=533682).